# A meeting room for 'use of' members and for hire or for 'use by' members and for hire

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing text for a leaflet for a co-working space and wondered which of the following is correct: "Meeting room for use of members and for hire" or, "Meeting room for use by members or for hire"?

Comment: Both sentences read perfectly well and mean the same thing. To my ear, the first one scans a little bit better (has a slightly nicer rhythm). They're both lovely examples of our native English [trochee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee)

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to be grammatically correct then the first sentence should read ""Meeting room for *the* use of members and for hire"